# Quote about meaning of meaning

Tags: reference-request, quote

Trying to track down a quote about the emptiness of the notion of "meaning of life", or the "justness of an entire framework of justice". I think it was by Friedrich Hayek, and I thought it was in his book *The Sensory Order*, but couldn't find it just now in looking through the book. It was something like

> If to have meaning is to have a place within an order, then that order
> cannot meaningfully be said to have a place within itself.

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective, he's basically abolishing the common notion of "meaning of life" as understood by layperson.

Most people's meaning of life is an outward place or certain desired state with his or her immediate surrounding environment. But as a thoughtful person, he may had realized this sounds already logically problematic, not to say semantically further. The critical insight here is the requirement of a layperson to have a meaning is nothing but to require certain "order" according to his or her own wish. However, if so, then to personify "Order", "Order" himself may not have a say to decide what kind of order he really wants to be. You know, if something really has a place within your heart, you definitely would like to manage and place it where you like as a chief architect...

Anyway try to understand a quote out of context is always a speculation, and also English is not my mother tongue, I just described my own understanding based on my own experience and reasoning.

Comment: Hi, thank you, but my question was to try to find the source, not to analyze the quote. I appreciate your thoughts.